# VLOOKUP results in #N/A with Exact Match

Tags: excel-formula, excel-365

Using Microsoft 365 Excel.

In cell K2, I have:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,METERS,2,FALSE)
```

In cell L2:

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,KNOTS,2,FALSE)
```

The result in L2 is what I expect.

No matter what I do to the equation or anywhere in the workbook, I keep getting #N/A in K2.

When I replace the named range in K2, METERS for KNOTS, the function evaluates properly.

Copying the named range works properly, so there's nothing wrong with the named range:

```
=METERS
```

returns the complete named range without errors.

Checking the value in F2 evaluates as TRUE, so the value is an exact match:

```
=(F2=MS!A210)
```

Oddly enough, if I change the function in K2:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,METERS,2,TRUE)
```

then it sort of works, in that it gives me a value instead of #N/A, but doesn't give me exactly the result I need.

I tried moving the function from K2 to different cell and using a different cell for the lookup value; then no matter what I input, I get 0.

I know the syntax in K2 is correct.  The named range is correct.  Everything seems to be correct.

Yet no matter what, I get #N/A.

Comment: Any rogue spaces in either the lookup value or the 1st column of the lookup array?

Comment: I use INDEX/MATCH rather than VLOOKUP, so the following may not be applicable, but if the value you are trying to lookup is a number, it can lead to issues. You may need to cast the lookup as either a string or a number and I found the following tend to work better; `=VLOOKUP(F2,METERS&"",2,FALSE)`, `=VLOOKUP(F2,VALUE(METERS),2,FALSE)`. I usually include an IFERROR so I can search by both formula variants when using numbers.

Comment: Need to see how your named ranges 'Meters' and 'Knots' have been formulated - do they both refer to the *exact* same range in the same worksheet / workbook (noting the option to specify 'scope')?

Comment: Show a screenshot of your named ranges sorted by name---

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gYsmIEkwX_oSS5YCUA?e=dAXvVW)/screenshot(s) refer:

Given the info you have provided, the only reasons I can think of why this could occur are:

a) Conflicting named ranges with common names/different scopes

b) Inconsistency between the two named ranges you're using

These aren't mutually exclusive (a different scope could lead to an inconsistency). I'll demonstrate the following in this solution:

- No issues arise when using two different names that refer to the exact same range / sheet / scope
- How easily issues can arise due to duality of scope (e.g. worksheet vs. workbook) for common names, and how either of these can be referenced anywhere in the workbook

Finally, I'll comment on the 'true/false' indicator in the *vlookup* function you mentioned, and propose an alternative / improved feature avail. with Office 365.

**Context**

Conflicts RE: named ranges can arise in several ways - e.g. when multiple sheets contain named ranges that have common names, when copying a function that comprises a named range from one sheet to another, etc. It's possible to produce a conflict from one workbook to another in this fashion too.

When copying such a function from one sheet to another you should see the something like the following UI appear:

[image: Resolve conflict dialogue box]

**Sheet 1 - correct referencing**

Comprises two named ranges (range_1, range_2 resp.) which both refer to the exact same range (with identical scopes).  Vlookups operate perfectly fine and produce identical results:

[image: Sheet 1 - consistent results]

Besides their name, *range_1* and *range_2* are otherwise identical in every way per the following in Name Manager:

[image: Name Manager - identical ranges/scope]

**Sheet 2 - conflict / error**

Copy of Sheet 1, with range_1 amended to only include the 1st column - the same vlookup functions as Sheet 1 now produce an error for range_1:

[image: Sheet 2]

Note: copying the functions from Sheet 1 have now produced the following in Name Manager:

[image: Various scopes - local and workbook]
**However**, I'm still able to reference range_1 from Sheet 1 per the following tooltip that appears when I start typing '=range_1' in any cell within Sheet 2:

[image: Tooltip referencing various scopes for common named ranges]

Thus its possible to retrieve what appears to be the 'correct' range for range_1 in any cell in the workbook by referencing the original scope (workbook), despite the vlookup in Sheet 2 producing an error.

---

*It this is not the case (and you do not have 'duality' in scopes for the same named range) then the only other reason I can think of is inconsistency RE: formulation.  If they are truly identical in the ranges they reference, then I would suggest adopting a single name (KNOTS, given this appears to function correctly) to simplify the workbook/functions and improve auditability.*

---

**Vlookup parameter (0/1)**

RE: vookup(range, lookup, True/False) -

True (i.e. '1') parameter will return an 'approximate' match (which distinguishes this function from alternatives such as index/match).  However, xlookup is advisable / preferred over vlookup in any case given it also has this feature and can reference to the left or right of the lookup column (vlookup works strictly to the right). Although it is more complex with additional parameters/arguments to consider. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60150&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) for details.

---

Comment: Thanks for your comments. After much frustration, I finally discovered the problem. The far left column of my named range contained values that (somehow) were not exactly 1 decimal place. For instance, 15.1 had somehow become 15.10000000000002. Even though checking that the numbers resulted in TRUE (ie, =(F2=H20)), they were somehow not exactly true. Since VLOOKUP could not find EXACTLY the reference number in the named range, it resulted in #N/A. To fix this, I simply rounded the far left column to the nearest tenth, then it worked as expected.

Comment: Ha! Floating pt. error -- strange that it worked with the one range and not the other (assuming the same far left column was used) - or were the two ranges indeed referring to different ranges in the end?  I've covered precision error of this nature in another post see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780959/precision-error-with-match-function-in-excel/67812949#67812949 -- vote up/down for the benefit / purpose of future users as you deem fit.  Glad to hear all sorted in the end -- happy (belated) NY btw :)